# Debugging React Native + Expo with Nuclide Inspector in real iPhone device?

Tags: debugging, react-native, atom-editor, expo, nuclide-editor

Hi I'm trying to figure out a way to debug inside Nuclide inspector not with iOS/Android emulator but with an actual device. The project is a React Native based on Expo.

I'm on Windows 64 bits (this is important for you to know).

I currently have it working outside Atom/Nuclide with the common Remote Debug JS (common Chrome tab with Devtools open) and even I've made it with React Native Debugger (https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger).

I'd like to avoid having to add "debugger;" anytime I want to check the code and instead using breakpoints inside Atom and all that stuff.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, and some years later.

Some days after this question, I totally abandoned Nuclide and went with VSCode, which totally rocks. It's the only thing I can recommend to anyone.

I've even posted an article explaining the experience that made me choose that IDE over Atom/Nuclide [here](https://medium.com/@nahuelhds/debugging-react-native-expo-with-nuclide-on-windows-fb47be0b36ad).